# Convert php file to pdf file by using mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I have just started to use mPDF. I got stuck at very beginning. I am trying to include my dynamic php file and convert it to pdf file by using mPDF. Here is my approach:This is my function to convert file to pdf

```
<?php 

include('MPDF57/mpdf.php');
include('template1.php');
$html= "template1.php";
$mpdf=new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents($html));
$mpdf->Output('result.pdf','F');
exit;

?>
```

My template.php file is only a html invoice table layout in where several content come from database as: user address, invoice table and so on... I do want to convert the html layout and content from the template.php file to pdf

But it is not outputing the file as a pdf file. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you want to convert the source of the .php file or the content generated by the .php file?

Comment: My template.php file is only a html invoice table layout in where several content come from databas as: user address, invoice tble and so on... I do want to convert the html layout and content fom th template.php file to pdf

Comment: `where several content come from databas as` so, it has a php code that should be executed?? `file_get_contents($html)` reads the file 'as is', without running .php code in it. Use `'ob_start()` before `include('template1.php');`, take the content of the buffer after, output, if needed, and convert it to pdf.

Comment: can u plz add the code?

Comment: `ob_start(); include('template1.php'); $content = ob_get_clean(); ... your code up to .. $mpdf->WriteHTML($content);`

Comment: Thank you. Can you please put it as your answer so that I can vote for it. And also one more query: how can I show open the pdf in browser from this php file rather auto download?

Comment: It depends on the settings of the browser and the content-type headers sent back to browser. Look at the answer - use `I` as second of argument of `Output` or remove it as the default value is `I`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `template1.php` has php code in it then it would not be executed by the `file_get_contents` function as it will read the content of the file as a regular text. You need to turn output buffer on before `include`, get the content of the buffer and use it for the generation of pdf. Something like this:

```
<?php 

include 'MPDF57/mpdf.php';
ob_start();  // start output buffering
include 'template1.php';
$content = ob_get_clean(); // get content of the buffer and clean the buffer
$mpdf = new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf->Output('result.pdf'); // output as inline content
```

Comment: `ob_get_clean()` seems to fail, but `ob_getContents()` works but then the clear function fails?

Comment: @BarclayVision try `ob_end_clean()` after `ob_get_contents()`

Comment: that is what i tried asked in new question - similar code but failed to return PDF. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292242/mpdf-not-generating-pdf-from-example

Comment: @BarclayVision check what `ob_get_level()` gives you - may be included files adding additional levels of buffering. Also disable buffering, check what output you will get into browser from the include.

Comment: `ob_get_level()` gives: HTML contains invalid UTF-8 character(s)

2mPDF error:

Comment: not sure how to disable buffer? tried `ob_implicit_flush()` at the start of my script.

Comment: using: `if (ob_get_level())
   ob_end_clean();` should turn off buffering, same results, page loads as normal html not pdf.

Comment: anyone have any help on this... example provided by @Cheery is not working for me at all, tried several recommendations and still no results from the buffer, just seem to return the include as the page but no PDF results. tried to dumb in down in new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33413873/mpdf-results-from-php-with-variables

Comment: @BarclayVision Try to create a pdf from some simple html page stored in a string php variable and printed while buffering, do not include external php file. If it works then the reason is inside of the included files, you have to look closer at what it produces.

Comment: That was helpful - it did produce results. But I still have the problem with my dynamic data in the include. It appears to be due to a certificate jpg I'm trying to use as a background in mPDF - no luck on getting a jpg to show in in the PDF.

Comment: @ Cheery Thanks for your help on narrowing down error, I'm still stumped with results not in PDF - see new question I have posed at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33413873/mpdf-results-from-php-with-variables-via-buffer