# mPDF results from PHP with variables via buffer

Tags: php, mpdf

Cannot seem to get this to work, everything from the buffer is showing but no PDF generated, if its all in the php as `$html = 'Hello World'` it generates fine?

-- REVISED QUESTION --
included example code to display certificate background image in generated PDF - results are blank PDF...

screen shot of `div.php` run by itself.

[image]

-- REVISED ENTIRE CODE EXAMPLE --

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);?>
<?php 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/TestCert/mpdf/mpdf.php';
$mpdf=new mPDF();
//include ('div.html'); 
ob_start();  
include ('div.php'); 
?>


<?php 
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
// LOAD a stylesheet 1
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    // The parameter 1 tells that this is css/style only and no body/html/text
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output();
exit; 
?>
```

-- CSS --

```
H1 {
font-size:14pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;
}

H2 {
font-size:14pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;
}

.certificate {
background-image: url("cert.png");
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 594px;
width: 1056px;
padding: 50px;
position: relative;
}

.certDate {
font-size:14pt;
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
font-weight:normal; 
position: absolute;  
bottom: 50px; 
right: 170px;   
}

.certHead {
font-size:40pt;
font-family:Trebuchet MS; 
position: absolute; 
top: 130px; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%;  
}

.certBody {
font-size:28pt;
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
font-weight:normal;
position: absolute; 
top: 220px; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%;  
}
```

-- div.php --

```
<?php
global $current_user;
$FName = "john";
$LName = "doe";
$FullName = "John Doe";
?>  

<HTML>
<BODY>

<SCRIPT>

var namedata = <?php echo json_encode($FName . ' ' . $LName); ?>;

    document.write("<div class='certificate'>");
    document.write("<H2 class='certHead'>Certificate of Completion</H2>");
    document.write("<H2 class='certBody'>This Certifies That</br>");
    //document.write("" + "John Doe" + "<br><br>");
    document.write("" + namedata + "<br></br>");
    document.write("Has Successfully Completed The<br>");
    document.write("<I>" + "Triage System Course" + "</I></H2></br>");
    document.write("<H2 class='certDate'>September 11, 2015</H2>");
    document.write("</div>");   
    document.write('<center> <input type=button onClick="window.print()" value="Print This Page"/> </center>');

    </SCRIPT>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only resolution I was able to make work was to put the style inline in the `<div>` and not call it from external `style.css` file... not sure why one works over the other but mPDF doesn't seem to like this one class in the style (all the others work fine...)

This works:

```
<div style = "background-image: url('cert.png'); 
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
    height: 594px; 
    width: 1056px; 
    padding: 50px; 
    position: relative;">
Hello World
<div>
```

This does not:

```
<div class="certificate">
Hello World
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating the content by using Javascript. This is interpreted by your browser but not by mPDF (which just translates HTML+CSS to PDF).

Try generating the HTML in PHP without Javascript, that should work.

Comment: I did, this issue is the cert.png referenced in the css, it seems to be the problem? It will not generate in the PDF

Comment: Might be a path issue. What is the request URL and what is the URL to get cert.png directly?

Comment: Yes, but mPDF might resolve paths differently, try using the full URL in the CSS. Always remember that rendering the page to PDF is a completely different process as rendering in the browser. The former runs on the server, the latter on the client.

Comment: I did have the css line as: `background-image: url("https://www.myserver.org/TestCert/quizimages/cert.png");` and still same blank results - I do understand the client/server difference, just is driving me crazy... can't even get a simple example image to load via the css

Comment: Try a path relative to the location of the script on the Server and without http://

Comment: i moved the cert.png file into the same dir and used: `background-image: url("cert.png");` still no luck... can't get even a simple html page with the css to work on image file.

Comment: adding `debug=true` gives me: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stylesheet' (T_VARIABLE) in /TestCert/story_content/PDFreport.php on line 18` line 18 is: `$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');`

Comment: the only way to get the image file to load in the PDF is if I place `<img src="cert.png"/>` into the include `div.html`

Comment: Looks like there is a problem right before line 18.

Comment: where ever I put the `$mpdf->debug = true` the next line is the error... looks like the debug feature is not very useful... "It's the bug"!!!

Comment: ok got debug to work (missing ;) now error is: `Error message detected - PDF file generation aborted.

imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format
File: /home/miemss5/public_html/TestCert/mpdf/mpdf.php
Line: 11103`